# As related to maintainability are mapping tables a better design than a large switch statement?

Tags: c++, translation

I am translating text files from one set of definitions to another, and I solved the problem by writing a small parser.  Once I've identified a symbol I end up at a case statement that decides which translation routine to call depending on what the user selected input option was (these are codes that mean different things on different machines).

I am essentially taking multiple input formats and converting them to a single output format, over about 400 unique symbols.

The problem is that as this project has grown from a couple of simple translations, each in its own header file, into a dozen or more input formats it is getting cumbersome to maintain.  Each of these header files contains a monster switch statement that produces the relevant output.  It all works but really seems clumsy.

Will I resolve the maintainability issue by creating mapping tables ( ie a 2d array containing input and output symbols ) for each input machine and using a common translation routine taking the tables as input?  Is there a better design I should consider?

Comment: @Seth I can afford to make a speed trade off, the overall speed of the project is well within the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hash-table type structure would definitely be easier to maintain but there is at least one tradeoff, namely that your giant switch statement would almost certainly be faster because any decent compiler would optimise it into a jump table. But it (depending on the implementation) it shouldn't be that noticably slower unless you're doing 50 billion lookups or something. That said, a hash table could be optimised to be just as fast as a switch statement.

Bottom line: if you don't need to be sure that you're getting every ounce of speed possible, then I'd go with a hash table. If it matters, profile.

You might want to check out [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/s/gperf/) which generates compile-time perfect hash tables.

Comment: Or if you do, then generate the switch as a pre-process using a table as input.

Comment: @Anton yes, and isn't that what gperf does?

Comment: May I add, creating the map from a configuration file grants even more flexibility

Comment: Never had occasion to use gperf, but it sounds like a good approach.

Comment: @dario_ramos I had had the same thought myself.

Comment: I figure that each time the project is executed I'll be looking at 10-20k lookups, but the project is executed during a time where the user is expecting a delayed response, so speed is not super-critical.

Comment: @Stephen then yeah, go for a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros to reduce code duplication. For example

```
#define ENTRY(ID, OUT) case ID: write_to_output(out); break;

switch (id) {
   ENTRY(ID1, "ID1");
   ENTRY(ID2, "ID3");
   ENTRY(ID2, "ID3");

   default:
     ....
}
```

Comment: The way he describes it, it sounds like each ID leads to a completely separate function.

Comment: No problem to use this case with functions. Also this code allow to easy switch between CASE and map table. Just redefine ENTRY macros.

Comment: So you're recommending `ENTRY(ID1, myfunction(params);)` as a replacement for `case ID1: myfunction(params); break;`?  You're saving 5 characters per line to make it harder to read, for no other gain.  Also, his question was `Will I resolve the maintainability issue by creating mapping tables?` and it isn't clear that your answer addresses that.

Comment: I provide very simple ENTRY macro. I show what if you use macro, there is no difference between mapping table and case.

Comment: I think this method decreases maintainability.

Comment: I provide very simple ENTRY macro. I show what if you use macro, there is no difference between mapping table and case. I use similar approach in my projects. But instead of macro I use bash based codegeneration. By using 8k lines off bash I generate about 150k lines of C++ code, html docs ...

Comment: @MooingDuck is correct about the way it's presently laid out, and while the macro idea would eliminate a lot of duplicate code I don't know if it will leave a particularly readable project in this case.

Comment: @vromanov: a map is very different.  At initialization he can load up `std::hashmap<std::string, void(*)(std::string&)> machine;`, and then his switch statement becomes a simple `machine[mystring]()`; (more or less)

Comment: You can use same macro for loading hashmap. #define ENTRY(ID,FUNC) machine[#ID]=FUNC; But I prefer case. Case have two important advantages: no dynamic memory (id don't like dynamic memory), and second - compile time verification. If id in case is enum value, compilec check what all cases are handled